# Homophone riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This should be pretty easy

```
You can find me at a grocery store,

Or a part of Chinese philosophy,

Either way, you wind up with the same pronunciation
```

What are the two words?

Hint:

> In line one, the item is a dairy product

Comment: Can you clarify the entry to line two? The grammar confuses me. Homophone comment to a homophone riddle; gotta love puns.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of messed up on that one, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The pronunciation varies so I am using wikipedia

Comment: Not the changes

Comment: Can everyone change their answer because I am using a different pronunciation

Comment: Well following the Wiki on Chinese Philosphy, I am unable to link any names noted such as Laozi or Mao to things in a grocery store. Maybe Mao if pronounced incorrectly. Maybe I need to keep looking.

Comment: It is not a person

Comment: I understand that; this is a rather large article :D Going through it is taking a little time but I'll find it.

Comment: I guess my other question is; is the grocery store you speak of like WalMart with more than just a grocery section; or more like a local farmer's market where it's truly groceries?

Comment: It could be both, I've seen it in both :)

Comment: Sorry, it is in wikionary

Comment: Just to be clear, are they both English terms? Or one is Chinese but is similar to a word with English pronunciation?

Comment: It is in dictionary.com but it originates from China and in China it has a different pronunciation

Comment: Is it safe to assume at this point that it is a food item in the English language?

Comment: The pronunciation yes, the spelling, well it works in scrabble so yes, I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could the answer be

> cheese and qis?

This could work because

> cheese is a dairy product and qi means life force for Chinese philosophy (qis is the plural form).

Comment: So close! Keep the qi and the answer is slightly different

Comment: Make it plural and you are almost done!

Comment: Truueeeeee -- how does this look? @Duck

Comment: Yay! Nice job! Finally, yay!

Comment: @Duck was this the original riddle too? (Or if not, what were you originally intending?) And thanks!! :D

Comment: This is the intended answer

Answer (score 3):

The answer could be

> Harry

You can find me in a romance movie

> When Harry Met Sally

Or believe in middle east philosophy

> Hare Krishna

Comment: I like this answer, but isn't one pronounced HAY-ree and the other HAW-ree?

Comment: @El-Guest I'm not a native speaker, so my pronunciation is not exactly exemplary anyway :D

Comment: It's a great guess though! (+1) from me!

Comment: It's not this one either

Comment: Note the changes

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Dharma?

---

> Dharma & Greg [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma_%26_Greg)

Although its technically a romantic comedy show, not a movie

> Dharma [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma)

Various meanings in Hinduism, Buddhism, Jainism, and Sikhism.

Comment: Good guess, but no

Comment: Change your answer if you didn't see the changes

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> SEEK - as in the search for true love
>  SIKH - follower of Sikhism

New guess after edited question:

> DOW - Dow Chemical produces packaging for many consumer packaged goods found in grocery stores
>  DAO or DAOISM (Tao or Taoism) - Chinese philosophy

Comment: Sorry but it isn't right

Comment: The romance movie thing got replaced since this is a homophone riddle there was more than one pronunciation and I changed it to another

Answer (score 1):

A first guess would be:

> Profit and Prophet; since a romance movie can generate profits, and a prophet believes in philosophy.

I think I'll take another swing if this isn't it.

Comment: Like you said maybe you should "take another swing at it"

Comment: I could give another hint but you would probably get it right away

Comment: No worries, I'll see what I can come up with here.

Comment: Note the change of pronunciation

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 things in mind, but I'm not sure of either

First one

> Fete and fate

Second one

> <s>Him and hymn</s>

Comment: Sorry but did you see the first line

Comment: I thought you meant it's not a specific person, but I can go ahead and remove my second guess

Comment: See the above, I changed the answer

Comment: Oh okay, let me think again...

Answer (score 0):

Could be

> dao / dow

since

> dao/ tao ("the path")

is a principle of Eastern philosophy, and

> dow (packaging)

can be found in grocery stores.