# A Windy Night at the Ballpark

Tags: riddle

I've seen quite a few homophone riddles here on Puzzling, and I would like to go the opposite direction and post a story that presents a challenge to find a specific homonym.

> It was a windy night at the ballpark. Tim was lowering his bat into his travel box. It was a good game, a silhouetted figure said softly. Who's there?! Tim shouted. Do not fear, whispered the figure; I am here to offer my services. Puzzled, Tim scratched his head and glared into the figure's dark blue eyes. Suddenly, the world grew cold and the figure stepped forward. I am going to ask you a question, and depending on your answer, one of two things will happen. Tim's face grew somber in light of his situation.
>
> In one you'll become a baseball legend.
>
> In the other you will fall asleep to never wake.

There is a homonym that can be found in reference to the second to last and last sentences. What is the homonym in question?

***Hint***:

> Tim's current situation gives cause for alarm.

***Hint***:

> The answer is you seek is not easy to find, to search is to look as words are defined.

***Hint***:

> Two hints before, now three that I've gave; the word which you seek, indeed rhymes with brave.

As a secondary/bonus question, how many homonyms did you spot in my story?

Comment: Are we talking about true homonyms (same spelling)?

Comment: am I allowed to answer the second question first?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/homophone-riddle You mean this homophone riddle

Comment: To answer all three comments at once; yes, you are looking for true homonyms. Yes, you can answer the second question first if you so choose, all answers are welcome. Yes, [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69587/homophone-riddle) was on my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had thought about this a bit, and I was a bit disappointed that the word

> rhymed with brave,

since I came up with

> DUGOUT: either the mysterious figure will put you in a baseball dugout, or he'll have dug out your grave.

That said, would

> GRAVE be the correct answer? One is the obvious hole in the ground; the other (thanks to @PerpetualJ!) refers to giving cause for alarm; being serious.

Comment: You just beat me to it!

Comment: El-Guest, the first reference is spot on; the second refers more to rot13(tvivat pnhfr sbe nynez; frevbhf); which is the second definition. This wasn't my best, but as a first attempt at this type of riddle, there is a lot to learn.

Comment: @PerpetualJ thank you very much! I will update my answer. What was the reference to the baseball legend?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's

> Pitch

Since

> The figure is making a pitch. 
>  Baseball pitch.

Comment: That makes more sense than my answer! XD

Comment: Unfortunately no; however, I've updated the hint to be a little more transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a random shot at this. I have no hopes on my answer, but here goes

Sounds like

> The devil is asking Tim to sell his soul
>  Both sell and soul are homonyms I believe. Devil is also a homonym, one meaning Satan, the other meaning harass or worry someone.

The hint:

> The devil is supposed to be mischievous

The second part:

> windy, ballpark, bat, box, game, figure, head, light, cold, legend, offer(?), grew(?), ask(?), answer(?), wake(?)

Comment: Those are homophones, but if homonyms is used loosely then you might be correct

Comment: Homophones: each of two or more words having the same pronunciation but different meanings, origins, or spelling, e.g., new and knew.  
Homonyms: each of two or more words having the same spelling but different meanings and origins (e.g., pole and pole) 
I believe I have used only homonyms.

Comment: Unfortunately no; however, I've updated the hint to be a little more transparent.

Comment: When you say no, do you mean my answer is not right or the definitions in the above comment are not right? If you mean my answer, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I am only going to answer the first question so:

> It says last two sentences so in and in (as in inning) which might qualify to be a homonym.

Comment: Quite the perceptive answer, but no.

Comment: Ok, well I think I will come back to this later

Answer (score 1):

This requires a bit of baseball knowledge, and I know the knowledge tag isn't here, and this is a stretch-and-a-half, but could the answer be

> SANDMAN?

This seems strange, but it's because

> In baseball, the Sandman was [Mariano Rivera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariano_Rivera), legendary Yankees closer who got the nickname for putting most batters he faced to sleep! In sleep terms, [the Sandman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman) was a mythical creature who lives only in the dream world, never in awake-land as it were. The choice seems to be between becoming one of the best pitchers to ever play the game, or becoming a mythical being who dominates the world of sleep.

I don't think this is the answer because

> either choice sounds pretty cool, although I guess I'd rather be the actual Sandman because Mariano Rivera is retired now.

Comment: El-Guest, this was a very good guess as always; and very informative. Unfortunately, this is not the answer. Hopefully the hints are helpful.